# Full disk encryption - adding disk

Tags: 12.04, server, encryption, lvm

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 Server using the encrypted volume with LVM option. I've now added another harddrive, that I wish to encrypt using the same key - and only supply key once during boot.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly possible (with my limited understanding of these systems).

An alternative would be to add a **keyfile** on your first encrypted partition that will give access to the other drives.

When setting up a **keyfile**, make sure you investigate and figure out a good size, as well as measures to protect it from getting stolen.  Also, I'd recommend adding a passphrase that you can remember in case the first drive fails.

The Archlinux community has a very good set of documentation in regards to setting up and managing LVM and cryptfs/dm-crypt/LUKS partitions.

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/disk_encryption
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system